# Curl in PHP, SSLV3 works in bash but not in libcurl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

This command works directly in bash:

```
curl --sslv3 -k 'https://www.test_site.com/test/abc.do'
```

It does not work in bash without both --sslv3 and -k

I've been trying to replicate in PHP with the following code but I get no response at all. Not even an error. Would appreciate any advice.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.test_site.com/test/abc.do");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. Typo on my part. Works fine with both the ssl and other command.