# How would i translate the curl command into php?

Tags: php, curl

How would i translate this command into php ?

```
curl -k -3 -X POST https://dsp-yourdsp.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/user/session \
-H "X-DreamFactory-Application-Name: NotImportant" \
-d '{ "email" : "foo@bar.com", "password" : "yourpassword" }'
```

what i have so far:

```
$url = 'https://dsp-yourdsp.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/user/session';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-DreamFactory-Application-Name: NotImportant')); 
// Covers -H
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Covers -X
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "email" : "foo@bar.com", "password" : "yourpassword" }'); 
// Covers -d

curl_exec($curl);
```

I think i am missing: -k, -3 Right ? or i have something wrong ? Does the above even looks right?

cant seem to find -k, -3 in https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

Thanks.

Comment: `-k` says to *not* fail if it's insecure.  `-3` forces it to use SSL 3.  Do you need those parameters?  Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183083/curl-in-php-sslv3-works-in-bash-but-not-in-libcurl

Comment: I've read what -k / -3 and the other letters do at `http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html` , i know what they do i cant find their equivalent in php, this is those were required by the api i work with so...

Comment: i think CURLOPT_SSLVERSION and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER where what i am looking for will test it now

Answer (score 0):

try creating the data as an array then json_encode()ing it before setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

$data = json_encode(array( "email" => "foo@bar.com", "password" => "yourpassword"));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );